# Links on mobile devices not working

Tags: hyperlink, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

I have blogger website [www.technonutty.com](http://www.technonutty.com).

Today I am facing some strange problem. All the website links work on desktop platform but not on mobile or tablet devices (Except links from widgets). Can you help me out with this?

(1) Open website in mobile. (2) Links on home page or any article page.

Comment: Which links you talking about?

Comment: (1) Open website in mobile. (2) Links on home page or any article page.